# How to get an NSDate from a specific time zone and perform calculations based on that date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have been trying to wrap my head around `NSDate`, `NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents`, `NSTimeZone`, and `NSDateFormatter`.

`NSDate`, `NSTimeZone` and `NSDateFormatter` are pretty straightforward.  The other classes are not.

I want to get the current Eastern Time (the actual date/time is in EST at the moment the code is run).

Then I want to advance that date by exactly one month, taking into account daylight savings that may (or may not be) in effect.

From what I understand, adding 84600 is the improper way to do this, but I could be wrong.

Can someone please post an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *oneMonth = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[oneMonth setMonth:1];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *oneMonthFromNow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneMonth toDate:now options:0];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSLog(@"Now in New York: %@", [df stringFromDate:now]);
NSLog(@"One month from now in New York: %@", [df stringFromDate:oneMonthFromNow]);
```

Edit: That said, your question is phrased a little confusingly. With NSDate, you don't do calculations in a specific time zone. You also don't get the "current Eastern Time". You just get the *current point in time* (regardless of time zone) and do your calculations on it. The actual conversion to a specific time zone only happens at output (when you display the time to the user, usually in their time zone).

Comment: Let me give it a shot and I'll get back here.